# Проблема с отправками фотографий

Tags: python, telegram-bot

делаю бота для телеграмма который по кодовому слову должен кидать фото с определенной группы к примеру
**бот** скинь картинку с **собачками**
и бот кидает фото с собакой  но возникает проблема
*ERROR - TeleBot: "A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. Error code: 400. Description: Bad Request: wrong HTTP URL specified"*
вот код :

```
import telebot
import os

from random import *

bot = telebot.TeleBot()
p = os.listdir("cute_dogs")


@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def get_commands(message):
    if message.text == '/start':
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "start")


@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def get_photo(message):
    words = "бот картинку картинка фотку фото".split()
    dogs = "собак собака собаки собаку собачками".split()
    plac = "пейзажи пейзаж пейзажом".split()
    space = "космос космосом космоса".split()

    text = message.text.lower()#для удобства

    if any(x in text for x in words): #проверка совпадения ключевого слова через any
        if any(x in text for x in dogs):
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "* картинка с собакой *")
            bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, f"cute_dogs/{choice(p)}")
        elif any(x in text for x in plac):
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "* картинка с пейзажем *")
        elif any(x in text for x in space):
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "* картинка с космосом *")
            #bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, choice(open('space', 'rb')));
bot.polling()
```

у меня в папке с ботом лежит подпапка cute_dogs и в ней 5 фоток как пофиксить ошибку и чтобы выводило рандомную картинку из этой подпапки.Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 0):

ошибка в
`bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, f"cute_dogs/{choice(p)}")`
нужно было открыть файл

```
bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, open("cute_dogs/{choice(p)}", 'rb'))
```

Answer (score 0):

`bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, open("photo.jpg", 'rb'))`

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Посмотрите, пожалуйста, ответ самого автора вопроса, и поясните, что ваше сообщение добавляет к нему нового.